# Filling column with several conditions using Field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression, field-mapping

I know the syntax in order to fill one field with only one condition  (field calculator):

```sql
case 
    when "attribut" = 'value' then value 
end
```

But how to do populate automatically one field with two or three or more conditions?

I tried the following command but it does not work:

```sql
case 
    when "attribut" = 'value' and "attribut number2" = 'value' then value     
end
```

Could you throw light for me?

Comment: Can be relevant: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301566/difference-between-quotation-marks-single-vs-double-in-qgis

Answer (score 5):

Your values need to have single quotes around them, one has a double quote and one has no quotes (field names need double quotes i.e. `"field"` and field values need single quotes i.e. `'value'`):

This should work:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "attribut" = 'value' AND "attribut number2" = 'value' THEN 'value'
END
```