# Difference between quotation marks ('single' vs "double") in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, syntax

I am confused concerning the quotation marks syntax ('single' vs "double") in QGIS.

I know something about the quotation marks and the way they are applied in Python scripting (i.e. comments, strings etc.).

There are even some related questions:

- [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)
- [Is there any difference between “string” and 'string' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143714/is-there-any-difference-between-string-and-string-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Nevertheless, I would like to clarify the details regarding the quotation marks ('single' vs "double") in the scope of QGIS.

For instance, if I type ***something*** in the Expression dialogue I will have a different output.

- `"something"`, it is written as

[image: something1]

The Output is `NULL`.

- `'something'`, it is shown as

[image: something2]

The output is `'something'` as a string.

What is the syntax or meaningful difference between quotation marks ('single' vs "double") in QGIS?

I do not know if there are any circumstances when other types of quotation marks are used in QGIS like the triple quotation marks in Python.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Double quotes](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#operators) indicate that the string represents the name of an attribute while a single quote is a literal string.

So in your first case you get `NULL` because you don't have an attribute called `something`.

Comment: My mnemonic for this is "Single for Strings, Double for Data". So to compare a data field with a string value you'd use `"name" = 'Fred'`

Answer (score 15):

Here is the answer directly from [QGIS help](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html):

> column name  "column name" → **Value of the field column name**, take care
>   to not be confused with simple quote, see below
>
> 'string' → **a string value**, take care to not be confused with double
>   quote, see above

Answer (score 8):

Double marks refer to columns in the attribute table, single marks to a string value. E.g. `CASE WHEN "something" > 100 THEN 'a lot' ELSE 'not so much' END` checks the size of integer values in your column and adds a string to fields in the attribute table based on that size.

Comment: Does this mean that the value of an attribute "something" is bigger than string '100'?

Comment: If the value of a field in column "something" is bigger than 100, then I write "a lot" into a new column, else the other text is written.

Comment: I asked because I do not know the syntax that QGIS is using. In databases '100' means a string and then '101'>'100' but also '99'>'100' because 9 comes after 1 in alphanumeric order. Does QGIS make difference and is it possible to compare by numbers `WHEN "something" > 100`?

Comment: Actually `'100'` really means a string, sorry, gonna edit it. Comparison of numbers is possible, yes.