# Using ELSEIF in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, conditional

I found [a similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39168/using-elseif-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator), but the answer solve the problem indirectly. So, here I reshape the question.

Say, in the following situation, how am I going to use `"ELSE IF"` statement?

```sql
CASE
  WHEN  "land use" != 'residential' THEN 'other land uses'
  ELSEIF  "area" < 1000 THEN 'small lot'
  ELSE 'large lot'
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your issue I can suggest trying this query

```sql
CASE
  WHEN  "land use" != 'residential' THEN 'other land uses'
  WHEN  "area" < 1000 THEN 'small lot'
  ELSE 'large lot'
END
```

Moreover, I recommend reading this article [W3Schools | SQL CASE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) and paying attention to **CASE Syntax**.

To comprehend the difference between quotation marks in QGIS please read this thread [Difference between quotation marks ('single' vs “double”) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301566/difference-between-quotation-marks-single-vs-double-in-qgis).

Comment: I read that tutorial and it seems that the `when` in the `case statement` is like the `elseif` in a `if-elseif-else` statement. Is that correct?

Comment: More like IF and at the same time ELIF