# Proper syntax of expression for selecting rows in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, expression, select

I have a long shapefile with various columns. I want to select only some rows, based on an expression. The column used for filtering is `"binomial"`. I tried so far:

```
"binomial" = "Axis axis"
$binomial = "Axis axis"
$binomial = Axis axis
```

... and so on, but nothing works. After understanding this, I would like also to add more names, something such as:

```
$binomial = "Axis axis" and $binomial = "Dama dama"
```

I am not used to the coding language of QGIS (is that Python? C++?) and I cannot understand how to select those rows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
"binomial" = 'Axis axis'
```

In QGIS, double quotes `"` are used to reference a field. Single quotes `'` are used to contain a string. No quotes for numerical values. The `$` sign is used to reference a current features value, like `$currentfeature`, `$id` or `$geometry`. The things you can use with `$` are predefined.

To filter for multiple values in the same field you should use `OR` rather than `AND`. This is because one field cannot contain two different values at the same time and `AND` therefore will never become `True`. An easier syntax than several `OR`s is to use `IN` like:

```
"binomial" in ('Axis axis','Dama dama')
```

The coding language of QGIS expressions is **similar, but not identical** to SQL.

Comment: Might be helpful: [Difference between quotation marks ('single' vs "double") in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301566/difference-between-quotation-marks-single-vs-double-in-qgis)

Comment: @MrXsquared thanks for the explanation! This worked perfectly. And thanks @Taras!