# Filtering rows by letter QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression, filter

I'm using QGIS and I want to create a rule to filter a dataset by size and by name (all areas over 80000 squarekilometers that begin with an A)

This is the expression I built:

```
"areakm2" > 80000 AND left("NAME", 1="A")
```

I always get an error message stating :

> Field 'A' not found!

Why does QGIS not recognize that A is regarding the first letter of the selected string, how would I need to change my expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In QGIS text strings are enclosed in single quotes (') while double quotes (") are for field names, so your expression should be:

```
"areakm2" > 80000 AND left("NAME", 1)='A'
```

Comment: Check this thread for more details : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301566/difference-between-quotation-marks-single-vs-double-in-qgis